# Formating decimal and digit together

Tags: python, format, decimal

I would like to convert degree to dms. I wrote a code but output is not like I want.

I want 2 digit sec, too.Instead of 3.56895, I want to have 03.56895.

My code:

```
def degree2dms(degree):
    int_degree = int(degree)
    degree_decimal = degree - int_degree
    min_part = degree_decimal *60
    min = int(min_part)
    sec_part = min_part-min
    sec = sec_part *60
    if sec == 60:
        sec =0
        min+=min
    if min ==60:
        min = 0    
        degree += degree

    sec = round(sec,5)

    return "%03d°%02d'%02.5f''"% (int_degree,min,sec)
```

Output It gives : 036°06'8.54578'', 034°03'5.55987''

**Output I want : 036°06'08.58975'', 034°03'05.58900''**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
return "%03d°%02d'%08.5f''"% (int_degree,min,sec)
```

#### Explanation

`%08.5f` will format your `float` with padding zeros (`0`) a total of `8` digits (incl. `.` and `-`) and show `5` digits after the decimal point.